# Как вызывать метод из namespace в Юнити и работает ли для С#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как вызывают метод `CarController` и вообще работает ли в С# `namespace` ?

```
namespace PlayerCar
{
    public class CarController : MonoBehaviour 
    {
```

По некоторым ресурсам говорится что Юнити пока не понимает пространство имён.

Comment: по моему, можно в using добавить `PlayerCar` или вызвать так :`PlayerCar.CarController  ....`

Comment: `По некоторым ресурсам говорится что Юнити пока не понимает пространство имён.` - где вы такие бредовые ресурсы читаете вместо доков https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/Namespaces.html ?

Comment: @Abs3akt, namespace это конструкция языка `C#`. Разработанный для этого языка движок/фреймворк, не может не понимать эти конструкции, он волей-неволей работает подчиняясь стандартам языка, работая в среде языка разработки. Рекомендую пройти курс по `C#` и у вас больше не будет подобных вопросов.

Comment: @Ildar `он волей-неволей работает подчиняясь стандартам языка, работая в среде языка разработки` - вот нифига. Если уж там есть fake null, то явно не всё там будет подчиненно стандартам языка ;-) Но это так, лирическое отступление

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Согласен, лирическое отступление. Это была общая рекомендация, т.к. налицо недопонимание автором вопроса.

Comment: @Ildar спасибо за совет! читал я на форумах про юнити такую инфу но Официальная документация не всегда полная поэтому уточнил

Comment: @Abs3akt вы бы еще при составлении подобного рода вопроса ссылки на источники тоже предоставляли бы. А то может там и ответы-то 2006 года))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский скорей всего может появится конфликт и за использования скриптов JS и С# в одном проекто или это не влияет ?

Comment: @Abs3akt ни разу не видел проблем с совмещением скриптов....Однако предпочтительно,кмк, писать на одном для консистентности